# discussing functionality of id's stringValue function?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I got a NSMutableArray object with int values
and I can get a certain value via :

```
int *v0=[[[arrayObj objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

there is no problem.

But
I got a NSMutableArray object with NSString values
and I cannot get a certain value via :

```
NSString *v0=[[[arrayObj objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
//raises error
```

**I want to learn and understand exactly what stringValue for...** and why this error occurs ?

NSString *v0=[arrayObj objectAtIndex:0];
works as expected.I asusme its some kind of pointer with null terminated so it can leech value.
Im not sure this line is also unicode/encoded string safe code.

in conclusion: 
want to know the purpose of stringValue with some lines o code snippets

Comment: `NSString *v0 = [ ... intValue]` is not a problem???

Comment: mistyped. question corrected. it was int *v0

Comment: Mistyped again; it's `int` not `int *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got a NSMutableArray object with int values

That's not possible, Cocoa arrays always contain objects. You probably have an array of `NSNumber` objects that wrap the integers, like:

```
NSArray *arrayOfNumbers = @[@1, @2, @3];
```

`NSNumber` objects have an `intValue` method, so this works:

```
int value = [arrayOfNumbers[0] intValue];
```

On the other hand when you have an array of strings ...

```
NSArray *arrayOfStrings = @[@"1", @"2", @"3"];
```

... you want to access individual elements directly, without converting the string object to something else:

```
NSString *element = arrayOfStrings[0];
```

`NSString` objects do not understand the `stringValue` method:

```
[arrayOfStrings[0] stringValue]; // crash: does not recognize selector
```

Back at the beginning, our `NSNumber` objects from the first array do understand `stringValue`. You can use it to convert the number to a string:

```
NSString *intString = [arrayOfNumbers[0] stringValue];
```

To make the confusion perfect, `NSString` *also* understand the `intValue` message:

```
int value = [arrayOfStrings[0] intValue];
```

Here `intValue` means to try to convert the string to a plain C `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

The error you will be getting (but failing to post with your question) will be *Unknown selector sent to instance* and this is because `NSString` doesn't have a `stringValue` method.

The approach you suggest is correct:

```
NSString *v0 = [arrayObj objectAtIndex:0];
```

**EDIT** (prompted by @Answerbot's answer):

The reason you are confused is that `[NSString intValue]` is used to convert the string value to an integer, as long as the string represents an integer (i.e. `@"123"`).  However you don't need this for string as the object is already a string.  It's therefore not provided.

Comment: so my point is this:

what is stringValue for ?exactly?
Im not looking for a solution.but to understand stringValue functionality

Comment: @N.Ramos `stringValue` is used in some UI controls to extract the string from the control or set the string in the control.